# Ubuntu 15.10 ZFSUTILS-LINUX

Tags: mount, 15.10, zfs

Further to some other discussion regarding getting the zfsutils-linux package working on Ubuntu 15.10, it does not appear that the normal zfs behaviour of automatic mounting during a reboot is yet working.  Has anyone else encountered this issue?

I'm able to mount my zfs pool manually, whereas previous versions of zfs stable PPA automatically mounted pools.

Answer (score 3):

The `zfsutils-linux` uses `mountall` to mount the pool, but `mountall` uses Upstart, which is not default for Vivid and Wily; systemd is.

To make it work properly you can add the [correct systemd init scripts](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/tree/master/etc/systemd/system) for ZFS. Put them in `/etc/systemd/` and don't forget to edit the files: the directories in there are not correct.