# ZFS Pools are not autoloading on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, automount, zfs

I have install Ubuntu 15.10 to a USB drive, and while everything works mostly, I have to perform a lot of manual tasks after a reboot.  I am using the computer for my media center.

There is a [similar question with no answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695218/ubuntu-15-10-zfsutils-linux)

I am trying to have the ZFS pool loaded automatically after a reboot, but it does not load.  If I do a `zpool import MediaCenterData` the system loads. In following troubleshooting:

```
$ apt-cache policy mountall
mountall:
  Installed: 2.54ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.54ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2.54ubuntu1 0
    500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ grep parse_zfs_list /sbin/mountall
<no output>
```

Working with /sbin/mountall

```
$ sudo mountall --verbose
mountall: Could not connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
$ sudo mountall --debug
mountall: Could not connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused$ apt-cache policy mountall
    mountall:
      Installed: 2.54ubuntu1
      Candidate: 2.54ubuntu1
      Version table:
     *** 2.54ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

zpool status

```
$ sudo zpool status
no pools available
```

Import works

```
$ sudo zpool import MediaCenter
$ sudo zpool status

zpool status
  pool: MediaCenter
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    MediaCeter  ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz2-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sda     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sde     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

I do not know how to get the autoload to work?  Does it have something to do with the fact I am running the / (root) off of a USB key?

Adding `zpool import MediaCenter` to the `/etc/rc.local` does work to remedy the issue.

Comment: can you post the content of your /etc/default/zfs and /etc/init/zpool-import.conf pls?

Comment: That question does have an answer...

Comment: @DavidCole The previous question now has answers (Dec 10) they were posted, but did not when I asked this question.

Comment: @ostendali Unfortunately, with no early direction available, I have since undone everything and installed FreeNAS.  I still have frustrating issues which is why I was moving in the first place, but I did not keep an image to be able to post the information you asked for. I have noticed a couple people have upvoted and favorited this question, so maybe someone else has the same problem and can post their information.

Answer (score 2):

From version 15.04 Ubuntu changed the default init process from Upstart to systemd, and a few things broke with this switch.

Some scripts needed to automount ZFS pools with systemd were missing.  See the bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zfs-linux/+bug/1521952.

The good news is a bugfix was released on December 16th 2015 to the wily-updates universe repository.  If this repository is enabled, you can update with the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

FYI, `mountall` is a helper for Upstart, and is not used with systemd, hence the error "Could not connect to Upstart".